# React router Link unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

Trying to add Link component from react-router and the following error are shown, have no clue why its happening

```
SyntaxError: ui\node_modules\react-router-dom\modules\Link.js: Unexpected token (59:11)

  57 |     }
  58 | 
> 59 |     return <a {...props} />;
```

Comment: What's react and react-router-dom version? Try `npm un react-router-dom` and then `npm i react-router-dom`.